# java does for loop COPY the object?

Tags: java, arrays, string, for-loop

This is my code

```
public static String change(String word, char gone, char here) {
    char[] chars = word.toCharArray();
    for (char c : chars) {
        if (c == gone) {
            c = here;
        }
    }
    return new String(chars);
}
```

and this how i call it:

```
System.out.println(change("supper", 'p', 'o'));
```

the result is **supper** I was trying to find explanation to what is going on ...

the `chars` variable is a variable that is refers to an array object, and which contains the characters of the String object `word`. then the only explanation that I thought about is that in the `for` statement, java actually copies the `chars` array.Is that correct?

some users said that there is a warning in my code,

but here you go, no warnings

[image]

Comment: What editor do you use, you need to let it format your code for you.

Comment: @weston sorry now i don't have editor, working with terminals :(

Comment: @weston please never mind, the code is formatted now

Comment: It's important. IDEs do more for you than format your code.

Comment: use `chars[i] = here` instead of the local variable `c` and it should be fine; try to avoid using the iterator in this simple loop as changing values while iterating will throw a `ConcurrentModificationException`

@Pankaj-saboo provided you with the answe.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
c = here;
```

Updates the value of the character, not the array. If you used an editor it would tell you that the assigned value is not used.

[image: IntelliJ]

Editors like IntelliJ above are free, so you have no excuse.

Comment: actually i just did the code in eclipse again, and i got now message `assigned value is not used`, the code compies without errors or warnings

Comment: Yeah, it's a hint from the IDE, not the compiler, saying that the operation wont have any effect. It's not a compiler warning or error.

Comment: OK, you mean to say "and i got **no** message"? Well Eclipse is not the best IMO, I prefer ItelliJ.

Answer (score 1):

The `c` variable is just a copied reference to the array element.

The reason for this is that the enhanced for loop uses an `Iterator` and in order to get the next element, it invokes the `Iterator.next()` method, which gives a copy to the original collection element.

In order to make it work, you have to directly set the new value into the array:

```
public static String change(String word, char gone, char here) {
    char[] chars = word.toCharArray();
    for (int i = 0; i < chars.length; i++) {
        if (chars[i] == gone) {
            chars[i] = here;
        }
    }
    return new String(chars);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

In for loop u had checked whether gone to chars each character and changed value but that changed variable not used to change the again "chars". you had changed value of variable c every time but never used so u got "Supper" as it is. so if u want to change "Supper" then use following code

```
public static String change(String word, char gone, char here) {
char[] chars = word.toCharArray();
for (int i = 0; i < chars.length; i++) {
    if (chars[i] == gone) {
        chars[i] = here;
    }
}
return new String(chars);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

What you did there is just change the local variable c not the element in the char array

Answer (score 0):

It's not working because

```
for (char c : chars)
```

here you are creating a new variable c which contains a **COPY** of the character you are currently iterating over.

What you could do instead is using a c-style for loop, iterate over each array element and replace the element within the array, something like:

```
for (int i = 0; i < chars.length; i++) {
    if (char[i] == gone) {
        char[i] == here;
    }        
}
```

Or even better: Skip the loop and use Strings `replace` method.

Answer (score 0):

No, java does not COPYing  object in For loop, but you are not using object in this example. "char" is primitive variable so you always receive a copy of a primitive veriable.